Google Form Script - Sending Mailapp.sendEmail but it is sending the number of emails based on number of variables added
So I'm using this reference (Google Form Search and Pull Spreadsheet Data) and it works....however right now it sends 3 emails with the same info. What needs to change in this to ONLY send one email?
The only values it's pulling from the Google Sheet is a lookup of the Shipping ID (Column A) the Status of the order (Column B) and what email to send this to (Column C). I have also tried adding additional variables and this script below then sends it based on the same number of variables I added. So if I have 7 var's it sends 7 emails. I tried moving the Mailapp.sendEmail out of the if (found) but that didn't solve anything. I'm stumped.
function installTrigger() {
    // This function instructs the program to trigger the checkID function whenever a form response is submitted
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkID')
      .forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm())
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}

function checkID(e) {
  // This function will parse the response to use the customer ID to retrieve email address and shipping status from the Spreadsheet Database
  var responses = e.response.getItemResponses(); // Gets the form responses
  var id = responses[0].getResponse(); // Assuming the first answer (index 0) is the customer ID)

  var found = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet_id')
     .getRange('Sheet1!A1:C8') // The spreadsheet cells range in A1 Notation
     .getValues() // Retrieve their values in rows
     .filter((row) => row[0] == id); // Filter the rows for the provided customer ID

  if (found) {
    var status = found[0][1]; //Column B
    var email = found[0][2]; //Column C
    var subject = "Shipping Status";
    var message =
        `Hello!
          
         The status of the order number ${id} is: ${status}.`
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
  }
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand if I have 7 var's it sends 7 emails. from your showing script. Can I ask you for details on your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

I figured it out...There is a installTrigger script that was running and createing a trigger each time it was run. So every submission it would increment the installTrigger and then send an extra email based on the total number of triggers. Totally random but ChatGPT figured it out and suggested to look up that in the App Script editor under the clock. Just deleted those and it is working as expected now.
